# MySQL AVG TIME Duration Calculation and Related Functions?

Tags: mysql, sql

table with login data of the website users with two datetime columns.  One is logged in time and other one is logged out time.

table has following  columns

```
user_id (user id of the
datetime (start login time DATETIME ) 
datetime_end (end logout time DATETIME)
```

From this data I need to generate a report or calculate the following

1. Daily AVG Login Duration for Users (i.e 01 March 2015 its 21 mins , 03 November 2016 its 25 mins ..etc )

second report is

2. Current Day (Last 24 hours) based on Hour AVG Login Duration (i.e same as above but only per hour AVG)

is there a way i can achieve this via MySQL query ? (or SQL query)

table is create is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_login` (
  `login_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_ip` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
  `server_ip` varchar(225) DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
  `country` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00',
  `continent` tinytext,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `datetime_end` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: How do you propose to handle user sessions which span over two dates?  For example, a user logs in at 11pm on 29-Feb and then logs out at 2am on 1-Mar.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this for the first one

```
SELECT DATE(datetime),AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,datetime,datetime_end)) as DailyAvg
FROM users_login   
GROUP BY DATE(datetime)
```

And for hourly :

```
SELECT DATE(datetime),extract(hour from datetime) as HourCol,
       AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,datetime,datetime_end)) as HourlyAvg
FROM users_login   
WHERE DATE(datetime) = date(now())
GROUP BY DATE(datetime),extract(hour from datetime)
```

Of course this queries have a few exceptions.. You didn't explain you entire logic so I assumed you want to group by the hour of the login and the date of the login..